# How to post data from iOS app to MySQL database?

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I saw a similar post to my question but his solution did not work for me for some odd reason and it is making me age faster than Obama.

Basically I want to post data from an iOS app to a MySQL database.

iOS code

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/phpfile.php?dishname=%@&description=%@",textfieldTwo.text, textfieldTwo.text];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSString *strResults = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", strResults);
```

PHP code

```
<?php

$servername="localhost";
$username="admin";
$password="admin";
$dbname="dbname";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$dishname=$_POST['dishname'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
echo "Name : " . $dishname;
//echo "Mail : ". $mail;
$sql="insert into RecipeFeed (DishName, Description) values ('" . $dishname . "', '" . $description . "')";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


?>
```

database image
[image]

I have no idea whatsoever to why I am having this problem. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: you're also missing `.` in your sql statement line after `$dishname` and `$description`

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota it does not unfortunately, I really think it has something to do with my PHP file

Comment: as i said , Echo each and everyline in your PHP file and see the console of Xcode , Try both the methods i have written .. surely you will get that working.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota Okay I think I see what is wrong.. It has something to do with my web server. When I try to open enter the link into my web browser, it doesnt read the php file but instead it just shows my default page. I'm very sure that the code you wrote and the PHP code that is given will work, I just have to check my web server.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota I'm going to play around with it and I will get back to this question and update it. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota So I am able to connect to my database and it is adding rows, but it wont insert any data so I just get blank rows. It is not getting my dishname and description. It wont show on my debugger

Comment: it inserts Empty record means it cant read the values from POST. what is printing when you echo the Post values?

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota It just shows me the description of that echo and the jsonvalue is null

Comment: Forget about the JSON value... but is it printing the Description that you are sending to server (jsonString values)?  Also can you put a screenshot of your NSLOg?

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota Nope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and here is the code below.

PHP

```
<?php

// Create connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "admin";
$dbname = "db";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","admin","db");

if (!$con) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 echo "Nothing happened";

}else{


}


if (isset ($_GET["firstname"]))
        $firstname = $_GET["firstname"];
    else
        $firstname = "Null";
if (isset ($_GET["lastname"]))
        $lastname = $_GET["lastname"];
    else
        $lastname = "Null";

if (isset ($_GET["email"]))
        $email = $_GET["email"];
    else
        $email = "Null";

if (isset ($_GET["password"]))
        $password = $_GET["password"];
    else
        $password = "Null";

if (isset ($_GET["timestamp"]))
        $timestamp = $_GET["timestamp"];
    else
        $timestamp = "Null";
$id = "null";


echo "FirstName : ". $firstname;
echo "LastName : ". $lastname;
$sql = "insert into Users (FirstName, ID, LastName, Email, Password, TimeStamp) values ('".$firstname."', '".$id."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."', '".$password."', '".$timestamp."')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
```

iOS

```
  NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/register.php?firstname=%@&lastname=%@&password=%@&email=%@&",firstName.text, lastName.text, password.text, email.text];
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your parameters via GET. So that you have to change

```
$dishname = $_POST['dishname'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
```

to

```
$dishname = $_GET['dishname'];
$description = $_GET['description'];
```

in your PHP script.

Comment: I tried that as well but did not work... I am sure I have my connections right because I used the same ones with my other PHP code to retrieve data.

Answer (score 1):

As mapek already posted code for PHP , let me post answers for **iOS part only**. You can pass the parametres in POST like below.

**Method: 1**

```
NSData*  submitData    = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dishname=%@&description=%@",textfieldOne.text, textfieldTwo.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSMutableURLRequest *submitrequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/phpfile.php"]];
    NSString *request = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:submitData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"request is %@",request);
    [submitrequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [submitrequest setHTTPBody:submitData];
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:submitrequest
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
  {
  NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"jsonString values=%@",jsonString);
  id values = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSLog(@"json values=%@",values);
}];
```

**Method 2**

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 [dictionnary setObject:textfieldOne.text forKey:@"dishname"];
 [dictionnary setObject:textfieldTwo.text forKey:@"description"];
 NSError *error = nil;
 NSData *submitData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
 options:kNilOptions
 error:&error];   
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/phpfile.php"]];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
 [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
 [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]]  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [request setHTTPBody:jsonData]; 
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:submitrequest
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
   NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"jsonString values=%@",jsonString);
  id values = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSLog(@"json values=%@",values);
}];
```

Comment: both methods did not work unfortunately. It might be my connections then, but it can't be because I use the same connections I use to retrieve my data.

Comment: It's not inserting anything :(

Comment: and the json values return null

Comment: Now , i have added Json string , so now you echo every where  so that you can see the output in NSLog , and post that response here.