# POST method not working in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post

I have tried every possible method to send data in post method using NSURLSession,AFNetworking,NSURLConnection;but every time my backend developer says they are not receiving any data,although my co android developer is successfully sending data in POST.I am totally helpless now.Please help.

---- Using NSURLConnection ----

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_id=%@&email=%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserId"],emailString];
NSLog(@"------%@-------",post);
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];//[post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@app_user_service/app_invite_email",App_Domain_Url]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(conn) {
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}
```

// ---- Using AFNetworking ----

```
NSDictionary *dic2 = @{@"user_id": [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserId"] , @"email" : emailString};

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[manager POST:urlstring parameters:dic2 progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success!");



    NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Response----> %@",dict);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: something may happening wrong in your code need, to look into your code

Comment: check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570676/how-to-post-data-from-ios-app-to-mysql-database/35571006#35571006

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota, your answer uses `NSURLConnection` which is deprecated. I recommend you to not recommend it.

Comment: And, what are you getting in response?

Comment: The response is They are not getting user_id & email from my end,though I have printed them both and they are happily showing me that I am sending the values correct.
@FahriAzimov

Comment: are you tried in post man clint or once try in backend side with static data

Comment: They have showed me using Postman client and at their side that is working fine.
@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: haha ha, hide this [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; and try

Comment: I am done with that too @Anbu.Karthik
Still no ray of hope for me :-(

Comment: have u give ur url and parameter I will try here

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik 
Here it is,30 is my user id in this case,

http://esolz.co.in/lab6/freewilder/app_user_service/app_invite_email?user_id=30&email=%@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS9, Apple added new feature called App Transport Security(ATS).

ATS enforces best practices during network calls, including the use of HTTPS.

Add the following in you info.plist

[image]

You can add exceptions for specific domains in your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>testdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: add once in your plist and try once, if you not get the answer we go for further step

Comment: I have added that brother/sir,as I am being able to do in GET method,the issue is with POST method only :-( Though the methods I am applying for POST is already tested in all other projects and running there successfully. :/

Comment: @KoustovBasu -- can you show your POST method with request URL and parameters ,

Comment: Check if you are setting @"Content-Type" property properly.

Comment: You should not recommend to allow all connections for the iOS app, instead, you could show how to whitelist the required hosts. Allowing all connections may break the security of the app.

Comment: @KoustovBasu -- in this place `NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];`, use `NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];

Comment: Applied this ---> [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
Still same response man. :-(
@Abu.Karthik

Comment: @KoustovBasu Add all of this code to the question, and make it readable, please.

Comment: Okay Anbu.Karthik &  Fahri Azimov

Comment: @FahriAzimov 

I have tried AFNetworking too,attached the code,please check.I have tried every possible way that can be used for implementing POST method for ios. Things are not working,son't know why.

Comment: This will promote app reject from Apple, instead whitelist the website. Credit : (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30732693/6042879)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are setting property like below

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Comment: Yes I have applied like that....The response I am getting every time from backend is the response they are sending when they are not getting data from my end.
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Comment: I have applied @"Content-Type" property same as u have mentioned @Kiran

Comment: Ask android developer what the value he/she setting?