# xamarin.forms httpclient.PostAsync not working on xamarin.ios (ios 14) but works on xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, httpclient, postasync

Below is my Code

```
try
        { 

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtr);
        var content =  new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            //This line below works on android but not on ios 14 devices , no exception return , nothing happened.

            var  response = await client.PostAsync("edtrapi/api/edtr", content);
             
            string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return Convert.ToInt32(res);
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            return 0;
        }
```

[image: xamarin.ios build]

[image: xamarin.ios info.plist]
[image: web api https]

Comment: are you using the actual IP of your server, or localhost/loopback?

Comment: hi jason , actually i have tried using the ip of my host. and i also tried the public domain name. but only the get method is working , the post method is having the problem.

Comment: if a GET works, then it's not a connectivity problem.  Is your request reaching the server?  Have you checked the server logs?

Comment: actually i tried to debug the post method on the server but nothing happened, it does not hit the breakpoint . the request does not reach the server. it only happens on ios , but on android it works perfectly.

Comment: the request may be hitting the server but not be routed to your endpoint.  Just to double-check, the GET request DOES work on iOS?  Have you tried using the different HTTP client options?

Comment: yes it does , the get request works on ios. Just the post request wont work.

Comment: i also tried <dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>

Answer (score 0):

I guesss you are testing with `Http` request.

Actually from `iOS9`, `Http` request is not allowed by default, since it is not safe, `Https` is the recommeded way .

To enable `Http` , you can set `ATS` in info.plist .

[image]

Or add  exceptions for specific domains .

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35884843/8187800 .

Comment: hi Colex, actually im using https on our server. and i already uses that setting in the info.plist , but still wont allow post. im using ios software version 14.8.1 but its working on simulator ios version 13.1

Comment: i also try <dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>

Comment: It's really weird, consider raising this issue on github : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues